# Neo4j - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Database locked

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, database-locking

I am using Neo4j embedded in my project. Am running a thread which runs continuously and updates the properties of a node. When I tried to read the updated node from another thread I got **java.lang.IllegalStateException: Database locked** exception. How do I solve this?

Edit: Also, if a user is accessing the database can the other users access the same database?

Answer (score 1):

Multiple users can access the database provided they connect to the same running instance of that database. How are your users connecting to it?